# Handle only one of the subtrees

Tags: java, methods, data-structures, tree, binary-search-tree

So here it is.I had an exercise on my exams about Data Structures where they gave us a class **'Student'** with just 2 attributes **name(String)** and **grade(int)** with setters,geters and constructors.Also there was a class **TreeNode** and a class **BinarySearchTree**.We had as fact that some **Student's objects** have been pushed randomly into the **BSTree**.
So we have to build a method which counts **how many** students at the tree who **aren't leaves** of the tree(they have at least 1 kid), they belong only to the **right subtree** under the root and have a grade equal or higher than 5.
How can i implement this in **Java** ?

```
public class Student {
    private String onomep;
    private int vathmos;

    Student(String onomep, int vathmos) {
        this.onomep = onomep;
        this.vathmos = vathmos;
    }

    public void setOnomep(String newOnomep) {
        onomep = newOnomep;
    }
    public void setVathmos(int newVathmos) {
        vathmos = newVathmos;
    }

    public String getOnomep() {
        return onomep;
    }
    public int getVathmos() {
        return vathmos;
    }
}
```

```
class TreeNode
{
    private TreeNode left;
    private int item;
    private TreeNode right;

    TreeNode(int data)
    {
        item = data;
        left = right = null;
    }

    public int getNodeData()
    {
        return item;
    }

    public TreeNode getLeftNode()
    {
        return left;
    }

    public TreeNode getRightNode()
    {
        return right;
    }

    public boolean isLeaf()
    {
        return right == null && left == null;
    }

    public void setLeftNode(TreeNode node)
    {
        left = node;
    }

    public void setRightNode(TreeNode node)
    {
        right = node;
    }

    public void insert(int d)
    {
        if(d < item)
        {
            if(left == null)
            {
                left = new TreeNode(d);
            }
            else
            {
                left.insert(d);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if(right == null)
            {
                right = new TreeNode(d);
            }
            else
            {
                right.insert(d);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
class BSTree
{
    private TreeNode root;
    private int size;

    BSTree()
    {
        root = null;
    }

    public TreeNode getRoot() {
        return root;
    }

    public int size()
    {
        return size;
    }

    public boolean isEmpty()
    {
        return root == null;
    }

    public void insertElement(int data)
    {
        if(isEmpty())
        {
            root = new TreeNode(data);
        }
        else
        {
            insertNode(data, root);
        }

        size++;
    }
}
```

```
public class thema_2_1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BSTree tree = new BSTree();
        Student s1 = new Student("ytytytyt",3);
        Student s2 = new Student("ytytujyng",6);
        Student s3 = new Student("gfdfgdf",7);
        Student s4 = new Student("gfd",9);
        Student s5 = new Student("gfgd",10);
        Student s6 = new Student("fgddg",2);
        Student s7 = new Student("gdgfdgdgdg",2);
        Student s8 = new Student("asdasd",6);
        Student s9 = new Student("dfdfd",4);
        Student s10 = new Student("hghgh",5);

        public int countSucceededStudents() { 
             //..............?????
        }
      }
   }
```

Comment: What have you tried? If you don't know where to start, you should do some research on [breadth-first search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) (BFS) and [depth-first search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search) (DFS). For your task, it doesn't matter whether you do BFS or DFS, so choose the one that makes most sense to you.

Comment: I started by taking the root and doing the following steps ```current = root.getRightNode()``` to begin from the right subtree.But how am I suppose to handle the following steps that I have to do ?

Comment: Don't show what you've tried in a comment (if that's what your comment was meant to do). **Edit** the question and show any code you already have there.

Comment: *"how am I suppose to handle the following steps that I have to do ?"* You search the sub-tree of that right node, using one of the search methods I already provided you. In short, you read the links I provided (this is called **research**), and you decide which to use to search the tree, then apply the logic for counting the nodes that meet the criteria.

Comment: I uploaded the code I'm using too. Thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

You are correct to start with the right node of the root.

Then you pass that node to a method which returns an int.

E.g. something like

```
public int countApplicable(Node n) {
  int result = 0;

  // don't want to throw null pointer errors!
  if (n == null) return result;

  // exclude leaves
  if ((n.left == null) && (n.right == null)) return result;

  // increment the counter if we qualify
  if (n.getthestudent.getthegrade >= 5) {
    result ++;
  }

  // repeat for all subnodes  
  result += countApplicable(n.left);
  result += countApplicable(n.right);

  return result;
}
```

So do you see how that works?  It's basically recursion.  Call the same method over and over again, with a well defined endpoint (e.g. if I am null or I am a leaf).